# Divide dataframe column by series

Tags: python, dataframe

Python beginner here so I reckon I'm massively overcomplicating this in some way.

I have a dataframe with about 20 columns, but I've only shown a small subset for simplicity. I want to get totals for red blue and none as percentages of the total for that month. So I thought it might be easiest to take a subset of these three columns then add the result back to the rest of the data:

```
data = [['2022-08', 10,'red',0,0], ['2022-04', 15,'blue',1,0], ['2022-08', 14,'none',1,1],['2022-04', 14,'blue',0,0],['2022-03', 14,'none',1,0]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Month', 'Balance','Type','Flag_1','Flag_2'])
    df2=df[['Month','Type','Balance']].groupby(['Month','Type']).sum('Balance').unstack().fillna(0)
    df2['balance_all_categories']= df2.sum(axis=1)
```

[image: dataframe]

Now I want to add this back to my full dataframe and make my balances for red, blue, none into percentages of the total for that month. I have many more than just 2 flags and I will need to make subsets based on all flags being zero, all flags being 1 and so on. So if I groupby month and type here, to access any one column they start to have incredibly long names I think, so I don't want to do that if avoidable.

Is there an easy way to deal with this? Thanks for any suggestions! :)

Comment: what is the expected output? can you put that as a table

Comment: It's unclear. What's your definition of 'subsets based on flags'? And why are they needed?